# Public IP resetting every time I restart Ubuntu Server Linux machine

Tags: networking, server, minecraft

I am running a Minecraft server on an Ubuntu Server Linux. I want people to be able to join publicly, so I got a public IP from my internet provider. I set it with the command "sudo ifconfig ens160  netmask " and the command "sudo ip route add default via ". It runs fine and people can join outside of my network with the IP I set up until I restart the machine. **When I restart the Ubuntu Server, the IP resets completely**. I have googled this and found some people want me to edit the /etc/network/interfaces file and it assumes I have that, but I don't. I tried creating it and adding all of the information the sites told me to, but that did not work either. Is there any way to set the IP and make it stay as that forever, even if I restart the machine?

Edit: The Ubuntu Server is running on a VMware machine's VM and the Ubuntu Server version is "Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS".

Comment: It would depend on the version of Ubuntu you are using. You have failed to have that in your question. Please add with edit.

Comment: What Ubuntu version are you using?  Where is this server running?  Is this a VPS?  Need more information about your server and its environment to really answer anything here.

Comment: I edited, anyone can help?